# Can I make specific lines visible based on user actions in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, tkinter, pysimplegui

I am creating a basic to-do-list program using PySimpleGUI. I want only the first line to be shown when the user runs the program. I have written the next 4 lines, but have set the visibility to False. When user clicks 'Add Task', I want the next line to appear. If clicked again, I want the third line to appear and this should work for all lines. Is there a way to do this?

Here is the code so far:

````
import datetime

#Formatting date and time
x = datetime.datetime.now()
y = x.strftime("%x")
z = x.strftime("%A")

i = 0
def add_line():
    i += 1


prac1 = [
    [sg.Text(f"Welcome to the To-Do-List for {z}, {y}")],
    [sg.Text('1.'),sg.InputText('',key = 'line1'),sg.Checkbox('',key='c1',visible = False)],
    [sg.Text('2.', visible = False),sg.InputText('',key = 'line2', visible = False),sg.Checkbox('',key='c2',visible = False)],
    [sg.Text('3.', visible = False),sg.InputText('',key = 'line3', visible = False),sg.Checkbox('',key='c3',visible = False)],
    [sg.Text('4.', visible = False),sg.InputText('',key = 'line4', visible = False),sg.Checkbox('',key='c4',visible = False)],
    [sg.Text('5.', visible = False),sg.InputText('',key = 'line5', visible = False),sg.Checkbox('',key='c5',visible = False)],
    [sg.Button('+ Add task')],
    [sg.Button('Save'), sg.Button('Exit')]
]

prac2 = [
    [sg.Text('world')],
    [sg.Submit()]]

layout =  [
        [sg.Column(prac1),
        sg.VSeparator(),
        sg.Column(prac2)]]

window = sg.Window('To-Do-List',layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == '+ Add task':
        """How can i use sg.window[].update here to make lines apear sequentially?"""```
````

Answer (score 0):

To set full row visible or not, better use a container, like Column element, for all the layout in that row. Just set option `visible` of specified Column element to set it visible or not.

```py
import datetime
import PySimpleGUI as sg

#Formatting date and time
x = datetime.datetime.now()
y = x.strftime("%x")
z = x.strftime("%A")

def column_layout(index):
    return [[sg.Text(f'{index}.'), sg.InputText('', key=f'line {index}'), sg.Checkbox('', key=f'c {index}')]]

prac1 = [
    [sg.Text(f"Welcome to the To-Do-List for {z}, {y}")]] + [
    [sg.Column(column_layout(index), visible=index==1, key=f'Column {index}')]
        for index in range(1, 6)] + [
    [sg.Button('+ Add task')],
    [sg.Button('Save'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

prac2 = [
    [sg.Text('world')],
    [sg.Submit()]]

layout =  [
    [sg.Column(prac1),
     sg.VSeparator(),
    sg.Column(prac2)]]

window = sg.Window('To-Do-List', layout)
index = 1

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    elif event == '+ Add task':
        index += 1
        if index < 6:
            window[f'Column {index}'].update(visible=True)

window.close()
```

another way is to call method `extend_layout` of window to add new rows to an existing container element inside of this window.

```py
import datetime
import PySimpleGUI as sg

#Formatting date and time
x = datetime.datetime.now()
y = x.strftime("%x")
z = x.strftime("%A")

def column_layout(index):
    return [[sg.Text(f'{index}.'), sg.InputText('', key=f'line {index}'), sg.Checkbox('', key=f'c {index}')]]

prac1 = [
    [sg.Text(f"Welcome to the To-Do-List for {z}, {y}")]] + [
    [sg.Column(column_layout(1), key='Column')],
    [sg.Button('+ Add task')],
    [sg.Button('Save'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

prac2 = [
    [sg.Text('world')],
    [sg.Submit()]]

layout =  [
    [sg.Column(prac1),
     sg.VSeparator(),
    sg.Column(prac2)]]

window = sg.Window('To-Do-List', layout)
index = 1

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    elif event == '+ Add task':
        index += 1
        if index < 6:
            window.extend_layout(window['Column'], column_layout(index))

window.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added that in and I have also made a lot more additions to make my to-do-list better. However, I have tried adding validation to check if each line has some input, but that validation is only working for the first line of the to-do list. I think it has something to do with my placement of 'raise exception' in within the for loop. Where can I upload my new code to show you?

Comment: Maybe post it as an answer to this question